# Summing intertwined terms of an array

Tags: code-golf, array, tips, javascript

I'm recieving 2-dimensional positions of two objects as a string with this format: `x1,y1,x2,y2`. The string is recieved from a `readline` call (replaced in the snippet with a `prompt`).

In order to get the horizontal and vertical position differentials, I'm writing the following code:

```js
[x1,y1,x2,y2]=prompt("Please enter the positions separated by commas").split`,`
dx=+x2-x1
dy=+y2-y1
console.log(dx,dy)
```

Is there a way to get `dx` and `dy` using less characters since I don't really need the positions? I suppose the main problem could be in the variable assignment which can probably be done in one step. I can use ECMAScript 6.

I don't really know if I have to precise it but removing the text in the prompt or giving variables 1-char names doesn't count, I have written them on purpose to clarify my question. The `console.log` is not part of the code golf either since the variables are supposed to be used after in the program.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Despite the close vote, I think you've already included the appropriate tags for such a question and this is indeed on-topic.

Comment: I would appreciate if the people voting to close this could leave a comment.  There is no way this user can improve the question without the necessary feedback.

Comment: Are you asking how to golf the middle two lines, specifically? Or the whole thing?

Comment: @Shaggy I would like to code golf the whole program, except for the two voluntary mistakes mentioned. I think the main problem could be in the variable assignment which can probably be done in one step

Comment: Could you state in the question what requirements you have on the input  and precisely? Also, it may not matter much here, but please state what version(s) you are limited to using.

Comment: Are the `+` in `+x2-x1` and `+y2-y1` necessary?

Comment: So we recently [adopted some new requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18613/20260) for questions about golfing specific code, and your post already does a good job covering most of these. One remaining point is, what's the source or context for the challenge? Note also FryAmTheEggman's question on I/O. Also, I think it would help to edit your comment to Shaggy about your goal into the question itself.

Comment: I guess the `console.log` is also not part of what to golf, since otherwise I think you can just substitute in the expression for `dx` and `dy`. Is the goal of the snippet to have these values be saved to variables so that they can be used multiple times in code that follows?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate No, they're not. The [subtraction operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) is unconditionally doing _ToNumber(lval)_ and _ToNumber(rval)_, whereas the [addition operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus) includes a test on the type.

Comment: @xnor I'd argue 5 upvotes on a post that is less than two weeks old is not really a sign of consensus yet, especially when you are both the question asker and the answerer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps something like this?

```
[x1,y1,dx,dy]=prompt("Please enter the positions separated by commas").split`,`
dx-=x1
dy-=y1
console.log(dx,dy)
```

Reusing `x2` and `y2` as `dx` and `dy`, respectively, lets you use the `-=` operator to shorten it a bit.